# Angular 4 download a file from a spring boot server

Tags: java, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I am working a spring boot server with an angular4 front page. I have a service to download a `.zip` file from my front using `HttpClient`. Here's my code :

Angular service:

```
getZip(fileName: string) : Observable<any> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/zip',
        'Accept': 'application/zip'
      }),
      params: new HttpParams().set('fileName', fileName),
      reponseType: 'blob'
    };
    return this.http.get<Blob>(extractZip, httpOptions);
  }
```

Angular service call :

```
this.myService.sendSql(this.sql, this.dataSource, this.fileGeneration).subscribe(data => {
      if(this.fileGeneration) {
        this.myService.getZip(data.zipName).subscribe(blob => {
        console.log(blob);
        console.log("Zip file download success.")
        },
        error => {
        console.log(error);
        console.log("Zip file download failed.")
        });
      }
    },
    err => {
        console.log('An error occured when contacting application server.');
    });
```

So basically I use `this.myService.sendSql()` to get the zip name that I will use with `this.myService.getZip()` to download the zip.

My request is like that : `http://localhost:8870/extracts_sql?fileName=name.zip` and inside my browser it works perfectly.

Here the server side code :

```
@GetMapping("/extracts_sql")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getFile(@RequestParam String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Configuration configuration = ConfigurationHelper.readConfiguration(configurationFile);
        MediaType mediaType = MediaTypeUtils.getMediaTypeForFileName(this.servletContext, fileName);
        File file = new File(configuration.getProcessingFolder() + File.separatorChar + fileName);
        InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));
        //Resource file = this.sqlToolService.loadFile(fileName, configuration);
        log.i("Sending zip :"+fileName+" to user.");

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                .contentType(mediaType)
                .contentLength(file.length())
                .body(resource);
    }
```

The issue is that I get a `HttpErrorResponse` on the angular side even though its statuscode = 200 , here's the error : `SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8870/extracts_sql?fileName=name.zip` 
Any ideas ?

Comment: did you got any fix for this. i am also working on something similar. Angular 9 ui and Spring boot Service. i am zipping multiple files to single file and sending down as resource. file is getting downloaded but it is not opening ...

Answer (score -1):

return this :

```
return this.http.get<Blob>(extractZip, httpOptions)
```

Comment: instead of this return this.http.get<Blob>(extractZip, httpOptions);